# How to pass file from servlet to servlet which present on different server?

Tags: java, servlets

Now I m trying to use `HttpURLConnection` but it doesn't work and I am not sure that this is correct way to do it. Please suggest thanks.

```
// RequestDispatcher rd =
// request.getRequestDispatcher("http://192.168.1.2:8080/EEXAM/WindowsWordToHtmlServlet");
// rd.forward(request, response);

HttpURLConnection connection = null;
OutputStream os = null;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("/Servlet").openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(0);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CommonConstants.CHAR_ENCODING);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + CommonConstants.CHAR_ENCODING);
    os = connection.getOutputStream();
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, CommonConstants.CHAR_ENCODING));
    writer.flush();
    connection.getResponseCode();

} catch (Exception e) {
    CustomLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e, request);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You're question is unclear for me. What do you try to do exactly ?

Comment: I am uploading file at first servlet and wants to pass this file to second servlet for further processing from first servlet